# Scraped JSON Data not Pushing to Google Sheet

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping, python-requests

With a lot of help, I now have a very interesting JSON dataset on wave info.  I wanted to push it into a Google Sheet, so I can sort and analyze there.  I went through and created the credential, connected to sheet, gave access, etc.  I tested just by pushing random values to the sheet, and it worked.

Additionally, the script (without trying to push to G Sheet), runs fine - producing result in terminal.

Is there some reason why this type of data wouldn't be able to go to a Google Sheet? Seems to be working for everything else I've tried.

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

import gspread
gc = gspread.service_account(filename='nj-waves.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1mbst-uaRGHWG5ReoFfIsazx0kpY7kXKIBqsRswy1y1Q')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


r = requests.get('https://magicseaweed.com/api/mdkey/spot?&limit=-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
# pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
# pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
print(df)
AddValue = [df]
worksheet.append_row(AddValue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save scraped data as csv file using pandas then store in google sheet from your system

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
r = requests.get('https://magicseaweed.com/api/mdkey/spot?&limit=-1')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()).to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: thanks - great, this is working.  When you say "store in google sheet from your system", are you saying to manually move? Or something like Google Drive for Desktop? Just want to pick your brain, I'm thinking I could use Task Scheduler to move this file into Drive every morning, but curious if there is a simpler way to include here? @F.Hoque

Comment: @Anthony Madle,Thanks, it's manually from your pc to google drive. Actually, Ididn't find  such a way. But You also can create an excel file from pandas: `to_excel('out.xlsx', index=False)`

Comment: Amazing. thank you - this is a life-saver in this script and another I'm working on. Great stuff! @F.Hoque